# VBA Regular expression 3 6 9 or 12

Tags: regex, vba

Trying to create a Regex to match 1 or 3 or 6 or 9 or 12, but 12 doesnt match

My code:

```
1|3|6|9|12
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because it stops at 1 in the Or. See number ranges https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/5023/matching-various-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use boundaries:

```
\b1\b|\b3\b|\b6\b|\b9\b|\b12\b
```